# Running multiple Flask apps on different subdomains of an ec2 instance

Tags: python, dns, apache2, flask

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running my dynamic website built with Flask.

I am unsure what the best way to run different webapps off the same ec2 instance is. I have read about application dispatching here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/ and about Apache2 virtual hosts here: http://blog.agdunn.net/?p=162.

I would like to run my main website www.mydomain.com off the ec2 instance (This I have working already) and then link to other Flask apps I have built, e.g. on www.subdomain.mydomain.com.

Can this be done either by using virtual hosts or on the wsgi layer by using application dispatching? If so, which is better?

Help and advice greatly appreciated, as always.

**EDIT: Thanks for the reply**

For now I am trying to run the main site, which is a flask app stored in `var/www/mysite`, off the main domain `domain.co.za` and another app, which is in `var/www/flaskhello/flaskhello`, off a subdomain `hello.domain.co.za`. For now the test subdomain app is simply a flask hello world app. I have the apache2 configuration files and the wsgi files set up as specified below.

The issue I'm having is that the flaskhello app is shown from both `domain.co.za` and `hello.domain.co.za`. For some reason the `var/www/flaskhello/flaskhello/index.wsgi` file seems to take precedence over the `var/www/mysite/index.wsgi`, and only changes I make to the `sys.path.insert...` line in there seem to have effect.

**Edit 2**

Now I've read [this Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/modwsgi/qJAGg5IXY3s), which is similar to what I'm trying to do but using DJango. Still no success, but it made we wonder if the `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` is what's causing the issue. I've tried changing this a bit, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing and cannot find any good documentation on how to use ApplicationGroups in WSGI.

Thanks again for help.

--

I have the following files

`etc/apache2/sites-enabled/019-domain.co.za` and `etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.co.za`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     WSGIDaemonProcess index
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/index.wsgi

 <Directory /var/www/index>
        WSGIProcessGroup index
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`etc/apache2/sites-enabled/018-hello.domain.co.za` and `etc/apache2/sites-available/hello.domain.co.za`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskhello/flaskhello/index.wsgi

 <Directory /var/www/index>
        WSGIProcessGroup index
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`var/www/mysite/index.wsgi`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/mysite')

from index import app as application
```

`var/www/flaskhello/flaskhello/index.wsgi`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/flaskhello/flaskhello')

from index import app as application
```

Answer (score 2):

Got this working eventually 
Helpful reading:  [Aagudnn.net blog post](http://blog.agdunn.net/?p=162)  and  [Graham's answer on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/modwsgi/Mr8y68ikj_g).

It turns out that one of my paths was wrong *blush* and that I still needed to set up ServerName and ServerAlias parts of the config files. Also, I couldn't use the same name for the two separate DaemonProcesses.

All working perfectly now.

My final configuration files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.co.za
    ServerAlias domain.co.za
         WSGIDaemonProcess www.domain.co.za
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/index.wsgi
     <Directory /var/www/mysite/index>
            WSGIProcessGroup index
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.hello.domain.co.za
    WSGIDaemonProcess www.hello.domain.co.za
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskhello/flaskhello/index.wsgi
 <Directory /var/www/flaskhello/flaskhello>
        WSGIProcessGroup www.hello.domain.co.za
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely doable. You will of course need to use vhosts, if you plan to use different domains, and you might want to look into virtualenv in order to separate applications python stacks (or even LXC containers to increase security a bit). If you're planning to use different applications, then they'll have separate dispatch namespace, so you will have to use redirects without url_for as argument, but actual hardlinked urls. This is very typical setup and it should be very easily doable - get back to us when you meet first concrete issue :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've edited the original answer with the more specific issues I ran into when trying to configure apache.